# Creating label from sentiment analysis score (range for neutrality label)

Tags: r, nlp, classification, sentiment-analysis

For a project, I'm using the R package `SentimentAnalysis` and specifically the LM dictionary classifier. The tool gives an overall sentiment score.

Now, I need to create the **labels** from this score. One seems to be neutral = 0; positive >0 and negative <0. Is this the standard approach? Even though the range for neutral is small, as it is only at a 0 score.

What are alternative ways to determine the labels from a score? Could I use +- 0.5 for example? Is there an accepted approach using standard deviations from the mean of my data set?

Thanks for your help! Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: Since the issue is not about implementation in R, you can expect richer feedback over at the dedicated statistics platform (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Here's how to migrate a question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228560/how-to-migrate-a-question-from-stackoverflow-to-some-other-sites-like-superuser